# Spring framework jar file comparison

Tags: spring

Can any one explain me what is difference between spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE-javadoc.jar and spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE-sources.jar

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-javadoc is the javadoc, the API documentation for the spring-aop library. Which you probably look at on the website but it's good to have a local copy in case your internet goes down and confirm you're looking at the documentation for the same version you're coding to.

-sources is the source code of the spring-aop library, the .java files that compile into the library itself. Needed if you want to build spring-aop yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE-javadoc.jar` contains the documentation

`spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE-sources.jar` contains the Java source files

Technically, a jar file is just a zip, so you can extract it and see what's in there.

Comment: Neither. Use [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.springframework|spring-aop|4.0.3.RELEASE|jar) instead.